# Can't run Bash scripts from within Mathematica 10.1

Tags: scripting, external-calls, command-line

I am working on [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) 8 (Jessie) and Mathematica 10.1 (64-bit) Home Edition. I have created a script named curl_fetch.sh. It contains the line:

```
curl www.google.com > html.txt
```

Running `./curl_fetch.sh` on a terminal I get the HTML output file as expected.

In Mathematica I tried:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];

RunProcess["./curl_fetch.sh"]
```

And I got the file html.txt, but with zero content and the following output:

```
<|"ExitCode" -> 127, "StandardOutput" -> "",
 "StandardError" ->
  "curl: /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/\
Linux-x86-64/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available \
(required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)
  curl: /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/\
Linux-x86-64/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available \
(required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)
  curl: /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/\
Linux-x86-64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available \
(required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)
  curl: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: \
symbol SSL_CTX_set_srp_password, version OPENSSL_1.0.1 not defined in \
file libssl.so.1.0.0 with link time reference
  "|>
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: @ilian thanks a lot - it worked! Although the solution is just one line it would be nice to have a full answer on details. For example running other commands will I need similar other settings ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(Reposting my comment as an answer)

The reason this is happening is that the *Mathematica* launcher script sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so that libraries included in the layout will be found and used, and that setting is inherited by any external process started from the kernel. But, sometimes it may happen that the external executable is linked against a conflicting system library.

As a workaround, try evaluating `SetEnvironment["LD_LIBRARY_PATH" -> ""]` before running the script. The default value could be restored afterwards by

```
SetEnvironment["LD_LIBRARY_PATH" -> FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,
     "SystemFiles", "Libraries", $SystemID}]]
```

Probably better and easier, unsetting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` could just be done in the script.

Alternatively, one can use the `ProcessEnvironment` option of `RunProcess` to pass the desired environment -- for example, the option value could be `Association[DeleteCases[GetEnvironment[All], "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" -> _]]`.

Comment: +1 Nice. How do you recover the original environment setting in case something breaks?

Comment: @tchronis Good point, answer amended.

Comment: @ilian Would you object to my merging this question with the earlier [(85291)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85291/121) to move this answer there?  It seems to apply equally without modification and I favor older questions in cases like this, all else being equal.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I feel this one is slightly more general and also more likely to be encountered (running `curl` or maybe `ssh` as part of a script may be more common than `emacs`). But I have no objection to merging in any case.

Comment: Okay, I'll trust your judgement on that and join others in voting to close the first one.