# Execute Terminal Commands Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

So what is the best way to do the following in ubuntu?

```
Import["!wget -qO- http://google.com", "Text"]
```

I'm on 16.04 and can't get any output.  A patch or workaround would be appreciated.  As pointed out in the comments `Import["!which yes", "Text"]` so there is some output that is available.

Comment: Does `which ls` work better?

Comment: @ilian I'm an idiot editing question

Comment: For the second question, try `Import["!LD_LIBRARY_PATH= wget -qO- http://google.com", "Text"]`

Comment: @ilian why does that work.  Is there any way to get the return value?

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used by your program to search for directories containing the libraries after it has been successfully compiled and linked.

Comment: I would try specifying the full path to wget

Comment: It is the same issue as in [(88059)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88059/cant-run-bash-scripts-from-within-mathematica-10-1). The workaround should not be necessary in version 11 and later.

Comment: @ilian should this be closed as a duplicate then

Comment: @ilian How would I filter stdin into such a function.